# SQL ORACLE Creating an existing table column chart

Tags: sql, oracle

I work on Oracle Sql Developer and I use this SELECT query for taking result.

```
create table column_craft (id number,city varchar2(25), data varchar2(25));
insert into column_craft values(101, 'Kork','numberone')
insert into column_craft values(202, 'Dublin','numbertwo')
insert into column_craft values(303, 'Dublin','numberthree')
insert into column_craft values(404, 'Dublin','numberfour')
drop table column_craft

SELECT *
FROM column_craft
WHERE City = 'Dublin';
```

And The result table is:

```
 ID  CITY   DATA
 202 Dublin numbertwo
 303 Dublin numberthree
 404 Dublin numberfour
```

Then I use "User Defined Reports" for showing a column chart in oracle. However when I test the query I see this error on edit report.

```
 An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
 Internal demo could not be converted
 Vendor code 17059
```

Is there any way to solve it or create a column chart in oracle sql developer?

Comment: Could you show us your `athlete_events` table schema?

Comment: Of course. I edited the question.However it is a sample of table because original one is more long. If you want to take data or want to see it you can look this link. https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results

Comment: I changed the query that you can see the exactly result and you can comment. If you solve this problem then it is going to help me directly.

Comment: Works fine for me, I just replicated your exact situation without the error. Stupid answer I know - but maybe check for updates to the SQL Developer software, could be a bug.

Comment: Maybe, everything is okay but my computer get an error because of company laptop situations.That's why it doesn't let me see the graphic.